# Scuffs on Newly Installed Roof

Tags: roof, roofing, damage, shingles, warranty

I just had my roof replaced. The roofer installed Owens Corning TruDefinition DURATION COOL PLUS asphalt shingles.

When I was inspecting the roof I noticed some scuffs and chips. Asked the roofer about it and he just said they were just small manufacturer defects.

I called Owens Corning and they wanted me to remove some shingles and send them in for testing. Not sure if that would just damage the roof more.
Really scared that Owens Corning will use these installation errors to deny any future warranty claims.
It was 85 degrees the day the shingles were installed. I think I shot myself in the foot by choosing a hot week to start the project.

Would appreciate it if anyone with knowledge of roofs can take a look at these pictures and see if I should be worried.

[image]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[More available here](https://imgur.com/a/7cLZB7i)

Comment: If roofs were never installed on 85° plus days, the South wouldn't get roofs installed for 7 months a year. I doubt air temperature was an issue at all.

Comment: Hot weather is better than cold for the shingles (less so the roofers installing them) as they are more flexible, less prone to crack, and the tabs seal fairly quickly.

Comment: Should you be worried?  NO.